# Meaning of `-l` (lowercase "L") flags in gcc/g++

Tags: gcc, g++, ld

What is the meaning of `-l` (lowercase "L") flags passed to gcc/g++? And where can I find documentation or tutorials on it?

---

I've tried searching `man gcc` and `man ld` for `-l`, but that has thousands of matches.

Example of a `-l` flag:

in this:

```bash
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 hello_world_extra_basic.c -o bin/a -lm && bin/a
```

`-lm` says to include the math library (static .a or dynamic .so?--I don't know) so you can use functions like `sin()` from `math.h`.

See:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12165016/4561887

But I need more detail than that:

1. **What does calling `-lgtest` or `-lm` really do?** I can clearly manually pass the `-I` include directories, and `.a` static prebuilt files myself, for instance, [like this from my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72108315/4561887):

   ```bash
   # to manually build "googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc"
   time ( \
       time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 -pthread \
       -I"googletest/googletest/include" -I"googletest/googlemock/include" \
       googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc \
       googletest/googletest/samples/sample1.cc \
       bin/libgtest.a bin/libgtest_main.a \
       -o bin/a \
       && time bin/a \
   )
   ```

   **What does `-lgtest` do instead, and what has to be in-place for this to work?**
2. Why `-l`? Is that part of what must be present in the name? Does "l" mean something like 'l'inker? Do these flags go to the compiler or the linker?
3. Why `-lpthread` vs `-pthread`? I've seen both before and don't understand the difference.
4. **Are `-l` includes linking to static `.a` libraries, or to runtime `.so` libraries? Where do these libraries exist in your filesystem?**
5. How does this relate to the output of `sudo ldconfig -v` [which I see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13513907/4561887)?
6. Can you add your own `-l` flags? How?

Update: searching `ld --help` shows this, so `l` must stand for 'l'ibrary, but is that static or dynamic?:

> ```
> -l LIBNAME, --library LIBNAME  
>                             Search for library LIBNAME
> ```

Comment: It could be .a or .so libraries depending on what is found first and what other linker options are.

Comment: @n.m., thank you. That leads to another question: which options can I tell go to the linker when I pass them to `g++`?

Comment: I don't know them all, need to read the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it figured out well enough to feel comfortable posting an answer. I figured out almost all of the following through extensive trial and error as I wrote [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75718815/4561887).

For full details, see the "Going further" section at the end of my answer here: [How to set up googleTest as a shared library on Linux: "Going further: general information about libraries; debugging; gcc/g++ compiler flags; etc."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75718815/4561887)

Here are some of the salient points:

1. As I figured out in the bottom of my question, `-l` presumably means 'l'ibrary. These flags apparently get passed straight through `gcc`/`g++` to the `ld` linker. See `ld --help`. The flag `-lmylibraryname` tells the linker to look for a file named `libmylibraryname.a` (if a static `.a` *archive* library), or a similar name prefixed with `lib` if a dynamic `.so` *shared object* libary. If such a library is found, generally in `/usr/lib` (usually for system libraries), or `/usr/local/lib` (usually for user-installed libraries), then the linking is successful.
2. Header files are also automatically searched for in `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include`.
3. Based on the naming above, `-lm` means there must be a file named `libm.a`, for instance, probably in `/usr/lib` somewhere. Sure enough, `find /usr/lib -path "*libm.*"` finds the following:

   ```bash
   $ find /usr/lib -path "*libm.*"
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
   ```
4. `-lgtest` works because a file named `libgtest.a` (following that same naming convention described above) exists at `/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a`, now that I've followed my own instructions at the link above.
5. Regarding `-lpthread` vs `-pthread`, here are my own notes from my answer above:

   > 1. A [google search for `g++ "-lpthread" vs "-pthread"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=g%2B%2B+%22-lpthread%22+vs+%22-pthread%22&oq=g%2B%2B+%22-lpthread%22+vs+%22-pthread%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.191j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) reveals this answer: [Difference between `-pthread` and `-lpthread` while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251828/4561887), which says that the difference between `-lpthread` and `-pthread` is historical, so on today's gcc/g++ and clang compilers, **you should always just use `-pthread` to bring in POSIX threads.**
   >
   >    The `-lpthread` library is now an empty binary apparently and doesn't do anything except satisfy ancient requirements where that library must still be included in some places. But, `-pthread` handles that all for you, so just use `-pthread` alone and be done!
6. > Are `-l` includes linking to static `.a` libraries, or to runtime `.so` libraries? Where do these libraries exist in your filesystem?

   Answer: either.

   They are usually found in `/usr/lib` (system-installed libraries) or `/usr/local/lib` (user-installed libraries), and their file names *must* begin with `lib`.
7. `sudo ldconfig -v` shows *dynamic libraries* only, which are loaded and available for run-time linking now (I think).
8. > Can you add your own `-l` flags? How?

   Yes! First, build `.c`/`.cpp` files into `.o` files using `gcc` or `g++`, then use `ar` to convert the *o*utput `.o` files into *a*rchive `.a` static library files. Then, copy your `.a` files into `/usr/local/lib` via `sudo cp -i -t=/usr/local/lib lib/libgtest.a lib/libgtest_main.a lib/libgmock.a lib/libgmock_main.a`, or similar. For full details on building the .o and .a files manually, see my answer here: [How do I build and use googletest (gtest) and googlemock (gmock) with gcc/g++ or clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72108315/4561887).

I think that covers it.

Comment: But.. why didn't you check documentation? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options and `man gcc` `exists at /usr/local/lib/` See also `/etc/ld.so.conf`  and `man ld` and `man ls.so` `sudo ldconfig -v shows dynamic libraries only` See `man ldconfig`. `First, build .c/.cpp files into .o files using gcc or g++, then use ar` Consider using a build system, like CMake, to hide all that complexity and for portability.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the meaning of -l (lowercase "L") flags passed to gcc/g++?

To link with a library.

> And where can I find documentation or tutorials on it?

Locally in `man gcc`, online at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs . No idea about tutorials.

> What does calling -lgtest or -lm really do?

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options :

> -llibrary
> -l library
>
> Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative
> with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance
> and is not recommended.)
>
> The -l option is passed directly to the linker by GCC. Refer to your
> linker documentation for exact details. The general description below
> applies to the GNU linker.
>
> The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library.
> The directories searched include several standard system directories
> plus any that you specify with -L.
>
> Static libraries are archives of object files, and have file names
> like liblibrary.a. Some targets also support shared libraries, which
> typically have names like liblibrary.so. If both static and shared
> libraries are found, the linker gives preference to linking with the
> shared library unless the -static option is used.
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the
> linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order
> they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after
> file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’,
> those functions may not be loaded.

> Why -l? Is that part of what must be present in the name? Does "l" mean something like 'l'inker?

Shortcut from the word "l"ibrary.

> Do these flags go to the compiler or the linker?

Both.

Compiler like means two things. Compiler literally is a translator which translates one language to another. But we call "GCC compiler" what really is "GCC Compiler Collection" - a *set* of many programs used to compile. GCC compiler includes preprocessor (cpp), compiler (cc1) and linker (ld). Linker is part of the compiler (toolchain). See for example `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1`.

> Why -lpthread vs -pthread?

[Difference between -pthread and -lpthread while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling) . And as you found out on *newest* systems, `libpthread.so` is empty. Still, for portability, at least for some time prefer to use `-pthread`.

> Are -l includes linking to static .a libraries, or to runtime .so libraries?

Both. `.so` is preferred over `.a`, unless `-static` flag is given, in which case `.a` is preferred over `.so`.

> Where do these libraries exist in your filesystem?

Note: shared libraries are like needed twice. First, by linker `ld` as part of the compiler (but really [Do shared libraries (.so) files need to present (or specified) at link time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017681/do-shared-libraries-so-files-need-to-present-or-specified-at-link-time)) and then by the `ld.so` dynamic linker/loader when executing the library. These are *different* programs and both have *different* implementations - there are for example GNU `ld` and [ld.gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)), there are `ld.so` from musl and glibc projects.

> The linker uses the following search paths to locate required shared
> libraries:
>
> 1. Any directories specified by -rpath-link options.
> 2. Any directories specified by -rpath options.  The difference between -rpath and -rpath-link is that directories specified by -rpath
>
>    options are included in the executable and used at runtime, whereas the -rpath-link option is only effective at link time.
>    Searching
>    -rpath in this way is only supported by native linkers and cross linkers which have been configured with the --with-sysroot
>    option.
> 3. On an ELF system, for native linkers, if the -rpath and -rpath-link options were not used, search the contents of the environment
>    variable "LD_RUN_PATH".
> 4. On SunOS, if the -rpath option was not used, search any directories specified using -L options.
> 5. For a native linker, search the contents of the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH".
> 6. For a native ELF linker, the directories in "DT_RUNPATH" or "DT_RPATH" of a shared library are searched for shared libraries
>    needed by
>    it. The "DT_RPATH" entries are ignored if "DT_RUNPATH" entries exist.
> 7. For a linker for a Linux system, if the file /etc/ld.so.conf exists, the list of directories found in that file.  Note: the path to
>    this
>    file is prefixed with the "sysroot" value, if that is defined, and then any "prefix" string if the linker was configured with the
>    --prefix= option.
> 8. For a native linker on a FreeBSD system, any directories specified by the "_PATH_ELF_HINTS" macro defined in the elf-hints.h
>    header
>    file.
> 9. Any directories specified by a "SEARCH_DIR" command in a linker script given on the command line, including scripts specified by -T
>    (but
>    not -dT).
> 10. The default directories, normally /lib and /usr/lib.
> 11. Any directories specified by a plugin LDPT_SET_EXTRA_LIBRARY_PATH
> 12. Any directories specified by a "SEARCH_DIR" command in a default linker script.

From `man ld.so`:

> If a shared object dependency does not contain a slash, then it is
> searched for in the following order:
>
> (1)  Using the directories specified in the DT_RPATH dynamic
> section attribute of the binary if present and DT_RUNPATH attribute
> does not exist.
> Use of DT_RPATH is deprecated.
>
> (2)  Using the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, unless the
> executable is being run in secure-execution mode (see below), in which
> case this
> variable is ignored.
>
> (3)  Using the directories specified in the DT_RUNPATH dynamic
> section attribute of the binary if present.  Such directories are
> searched  only
> to  find  those  objects  required by DT_NEEDED (direct dependencies) entries and do not apply to those objects' children,
> which must them‐
> selves have their own DT_RUNPATH entries.  This is unlike DT_RPATH, which is applied to searches for all children in the
> dependency tree.
>
> (4)  From the cache file /etc/ld.so.cache, which contains a
> compiled list of candidate shared objects previously found in the
> augmented  library
> path.   If, however, the binary was linked with the -z nodeflib linker option, shared objects in the default paths are
> skipped.  Shared ob‐
> jects installed in hardware capability directories (see below) are preferred to other shared objects.
>
> (5)  In the default path /lib, and then /usr/lib.  (On some 64-bit
> architectures, the default paths for 64-bit shared objects  are
> /lib64,  and
> then /usr/lib64.)  If the binary was linked with the -z nodeflib linker option, this step is skipped.

> How does this relate to the output of sudo ldconfig -v which I see here?

`ld.so` searches the cache created by `ldconfig`. The output of `ldconfig` shows the content of that cache. See `man ldconfig`.

> Can you add your own -l flags? How?

You can type `-lanything`. You can also create a shared library or a static library named `libanything.so` and add it to compiler linker search paths.