# dlopen() finds a lib in the same directory but not in a differnt dir even with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dlopen

**Update**

I was being foolish - I had a check to see if the file existed (in the same folder) before passing it to `dlopen()`.. so the question is not valid, I will close it.

**Original Question**

For an exectuable that needs to link to a bunch of shared libraries in a different folder you can just do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/other/folder` and then when you run your exectuable it can find them - and that is all working as expected for me.

However one of my applications uses dlopen() to open a shared library at runtime (in a plug-in like way). I am using `dlopen("libsome_lilb.so", RTLD_NOW)`.

So, this works if the plugin shared lib is in the same folder, but not if its in some other folder. So then I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and re-try, but it still fails to find the library.

This is related to this question: [c-linux-dlopen-cant-find-so-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715774/c-linux-dlopen-cant-find-so-library)

But that OP seems to have a varaition of this issue where they are trying to open a .so in the same folder... so I can't see a solution there.

Not quite sure what to tinker with now... maybe some of the options for `dlopen("name", options);`? (that's a guess)

Comment: maybe your program has setuid or setgid? This prevents it from using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @bartop I have not intentionally set that - I am guessing I would know if I had done this? My makefile is fairly simple, I don't see any such option...

Comment: for the sake of ruling out obvious problems - just check it with `ls -l` and maybe extend question with the info

Comment: The man page of dlopen specifies where it searches.

Comment: What does `dlerror()` return?

Comment: @yugr ...ummmm, sorry - its my crap code  ... I was checking if the file exists (in the same dir) before passing it to `dlopen()`. So I was not seeing me dlerror() output. I only noticed this when I went to look why as a result of your question and spotting my error. It works fine now... feel free to write your comment as an answer and I can mark it up - I will edit my question to reflect my foolishness :o - and then I wil close my question